# Give something to somebody vs Give somebody something

Tags: grammar, word-order

1- I gave the keys to Sarah.

2- I gave Sarah the keys.

I've already know the grammatical role of "keys" and it's object.
What about the "Sarah"? Is it the second object or what? (In both examples)

I need the word order & exact structure for further analysis could you help me ?

Comment: Your example #2 is a ***ditransitive*** usage - it's got ***two*** objects without any prepositions. The keys (the thing given) are the ***direct*** object, and Sarah (the receiver) is the ***indirect*** object.

Comment: Note that with some verb + object combinations, a ditransitive verb becomes monotransitive if you remove the indirect object - ditransitive ***He bought me a coffee*** becomes monotransitive ***He bough a coffee*** (note that ***He bought me*** isn't valid in any normal context). Also note that ***to give*** almost *always* requires both objects (thing given *and* who it's given to), but it's not normally (or *not necessarily*) still called a "ditransitive" usage if you have a preposition as per your example #1.

Comment: Thanks a million 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's example #2 is a [***ditransitive***](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/ditransitive-verbs/) usage - it's got two objects with no prepositions. The keys (the thing given) are the ***direct** object*, and Sarah (the receiver) is the ***indirect** object*.

Note that with some verb + object combinations, a ditransitive verb becomes monotransitive by removing the indirect object. Hence ditransitive ***He bought me a coffee*** becomes monotransitive ***He bought a coffee*** (note that ***He bought me*** isn't valid in any normal context). Also note that ***to give*** almost always requires both objects (the thing given *and* who it's given to), but it's not normally (or at least not *necessarily*) still called a "ditransitive" usage if there's a preposition, as per OP's example #1.

Answer (score 3):

Many verbs of giving or showing are *ditransitive* in English, and allow these two different argument structures:

> I *gave* the keys to Sarah. <=> I *gave* Sarah the keys.

> Sarah *showed* the book to me. <=> Sarah *showed* me the book.

> Tom *offered* a cake to them. <=> Tom *offered* them a cake.

In each case the meaning is the same, and you can see from the *to* that the recipient is semantically an indirect object, and the thing given, shown, or offered is a direct object.

As long as both are present, you can put the indirect object before the direct, without a preposition.

Other verbs which can be used in this way are *promise*, *present* (in the sense of "give in a ceremonial way"), and *sell*.

This is also possible with some other verbs with a "benefactive" object, using the preposition "for":

> I baked a cake for Sally. <=> I baked Sally a cake.

> He built a house for us <=> He built us a house.

> Will you buy some oranges for me? <=> Will you buy me some oranges?

The benefactive (the person you're done the action for) isn't part of the meaning, so it isn't required (He built a house. I baked a cake) but if you expressed it, you can use this ditransitive construction.

But you can't do this with every verb

> *I washed the windows for her.* But not **I washed her the windows*.

I think the restriction is that the beneficiary must end up with something they didn't have before.

Comment: Thanks a million 

Comment: I'm pretty sure "beneficiary must end up with something they didn't have before" is the "standard, accepted" restriction on the ditransitive prepositionless usage. But I think it's the fact that John Lawler's American that sets him against, say, [***She showed me it***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244659/she-showed-me-it#comment529382_244659) (which I have no problem with, in the right context). And at the margins, I can even live with *Will one of you kids open Aunt Ethel the door!* (That "beneficiary acquires something" doesn't really constrain *my* inner grammarian! :)